# how to store a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
$id=721914338;
setcookie("id",$id,time()+1200,'/');
?>
```

This is just a example  so I can ask my question . My question is this that I am capturing id from facebook , google or twitter . I am inserting into the database but the problem is this that when i store it in the cookie and use this cookie in the next page or any other page . By using the sql query whether the user has this id or not which is stored in cookie . As a developer , any user has knowledge about INSPECT ELEMENT , he or she can read my id so how to protect from hacking ? please can anyone help me ?

I don't want to store it in session, I want to store it in cookie only . Is there any to encrypt the id and in every page decrypt it use it . Is there any when the user  refreshes the page , the timer will start again

Comment: Your PHP code is not displayed client-side and users can't see that. So, what ***exactly*** is your question?

Comment: you could add id to database and fetch it as needed..!

Comment: This is probably more suited to be stored in a session.

Comment: A user can change a cookie value/name, like in chrome, but a session cookie might be better for this situation?

Comment: Why do people keep giving answers in comments? I'm very tempted to copy/paste what you say in the box below and make a good answer that'll probably be accepted. Just saying…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this id into session variable. Every time a user is login into site you fetch its id from data base and store into session variable in php. Using session you can get the value in any page.